# 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier <addressCell>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier addressCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableview has no cell registered under the name you have provided.
You have to set the identifier of the cells in interface builder or you have to programmatically register nibs with the tableview.